# How to change 'Alt roots' in perforce?

Tags: perforce

When issuing a `p4` command e.g. `p4 client` no matter current working directory is inside or outside the perforce workspace, the command output is

```
Error: p4 client root is not '/workspace_dir'. 
Please make sure that your Perforce workspace has the 'Alt roots' set to '/workspace_dir'.
```

P4V client works ok.

How can change 'Alt roots' setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the `p4 client` command to edit your `AltRoots`.

If you do not have multiple client roots (which is a pretty rare situation), you do not need to set the `AltRoots` field.  The error you quote is **not** a Perforce error that I'm familiar with and may be some sort of wrapper script or trigger that is configured to expect an `AltRoot` for reasons that may not be sound.  I'd check with your Perforce admin for clarification.

Comment: It turned out the error message was caused by wrong value of environment variable `P4CLIENT`.